# AWS ECS FARGATE - unable to pull image from docker private repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, task, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm trying to create an ECS Cluster with a task pulling image from my private docker repository.
I created a secret in AWS SecretsManager.
I created policy with following parameters.

```
  "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:123456789:secret:docker_private_repo-123456"
```

I added new policy to "ecsTaskExecutionRole" that is created by ECS Task Definition process.

But unfortunately, task always stopped.

I tried to do everything in following tutorials.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-private-registry-authentication-support-for-aws-fargate/

I'm getting this error.

"Stopped reason ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to get registry auth from asm: service call has been retried 1 time(s): unable to unmarshal secret value of authorization data from asm: i..."

Launch type FARGATE
Platform version 1.4.0

Can anyone help me, please.
Thank you..

Task Definition:

```
    {
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/WebFTask",
          "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "repositoryCredentials": {
        "credentialsParameter": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:123456789:secret:docker_private_repo-123456"
      },
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": 512,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "docker.io/username/imageName:latest",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "WebContariner"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "2048",
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:123456789:task-definition/WebFTask:6",
  "family": "WebFTask",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.private-registry-authentication.secretsmanager"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.21"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "cpu": "1024",
  "revision": 6,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

***ecsTaskExecutionRole:***

**Policy 1:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Policy 2:**

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:123456789:secret:docker_private_repo-123456c"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your task definition? What are permissions in ecsTaskExecutionRole? Sadly, your questions lacks details.

Answer (score 0):

Your task definition shows **lack of task role**:

```
"taskRoleArn": null,
```

Seems you created it, but you haven't assigned it to the task.

Comment: I left it default. What sould it be? With which polices?

Comment: @ŞamilAydoğan Default one is empty. Just use your `executionRoleArn` as `taskRoleArn`.

Comment: thank you. I edited question. Changed taskRoleArn as you described. But didn't help. It still stops with same reason.